# Access accuracy and cross-entropy information in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using object_detection from the models/research tensorflow repository. I managed to successfully train a model, but I miss the accuracy and cross-entropy information when controlling the progress of my training with tensorboard.

Do I need to calculate the accuracy and add it to tb myself or is it already there and I am doing something wrong? In case I have to add it, would trainer.py be the right place to do so?

Answer (score 0):

TensorBoard calculates these metrics for you, there is no need to go down this way. When you open tensorboard via `tensorboard --logdir tf_files/training_summaries &` (in Terminal), where `tf_files/training_summaries` is the path to where your trained model is, TensorBoard will provide so called summaries - for scalar variables (accuracy and cross-entropy), histograms, and images. You are also free to recalculate these if you wish, but the point, other than testing, would be none.